# In a Java Map <Integer, Double[]>, do I need to put the Double[] after getting and modifying?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

A quick question which maybe is lame.

In the following code:

```
Map<Integer, Double[]> dataMap = new Map<Integer, Double[]>();
dataMap.put(1, new Double[]{100,100});
Double[] dob = dataMap.get(1);
dob[0] = 100;
dob[1] = 200;
dataMap.put(1, dob);
```

Is the last "dataMap.put" instruction necessary? or will the dataMap.get(1) yield a reference to the array which will then be modified directly in the later statements.

I know that, in the case of mutable objects (e.g. Map), Map.get() will give me the reference to the desired object, however with an array of Doubles (whose element type e.g. `Double` are immutable) I am not sure if I get a reference to the array in the Map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the final statement isn't necessary - because the map only contains references to arrays, as you've mentioned. An array is a mutable object, even though `Double` isn't - it's like having an object with a `setName(String)` method - just because `String` is immutable, the container type isn't.

Note that if you do this, another thread<sup>1</sup> may see *half* the change (i.e. the setting of the first element to 100) without seeing the second element set to 200. Is that okay? If not, you could think about creating a *new* array instead:

```
Map<Integer, Double[]> dataMap = new HashMap<Integer, Double[]>();
dataMap.put(1, new Double[]{100,100});
// Other stuff...

// Replace value in map with a reference to a different array.
Double[] dob = new Double[] { 100, 200 };
dataMap.put(1, dob);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> This is assuming you're using a thread-safe map to start with, of course...

Answer (score 1):

The `Double` itself is immutable, but that is irrelevant as far as the array is concerned.

Think of each `Double` as an indestructible box. Even though the boxes are indestructible, you can still throw them away and replace them with something else as far as your inventory is concerned.